# Nest columns inside of another column

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to nest a group of columns inside a greater container column. I was intending on using a grid for this but am open to suggestions. I would like the result to look as follows in that row 1 col 1 and row 2 col 1 have sub columns 1a, 1b, 1c, and, 1d.

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Name="row0"  Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="row1"  Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="row2"  Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="row3"  Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="row4"  Height="35"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col0" Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col1" Width="400"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col2" Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Have you considered using Grid.ColumnSpan instead of nested grids?

Comment: Take the suggestion of @wkl and see if using ColumnSpan won't work better for you than nesting Grids. Besides that, I just want to add that the Grid is definitely the way to go here, as long as the amount of columns and rows is not dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested Grids do work, however `ColumnSpan` will keep your different columns lined up if you have dynamic content.

In my example below I created three new columns for the middle section.
Then for columns like row 0 col 1, I simply told it to span across 4 columns

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Name="row0" Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Name="row1" Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Name="row2" Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Name="row3" Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Name="row4" Height="35" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col0" Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col1" Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col2" Width="125" />
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col3" Width="125" />
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col4" Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col5" Width="75" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
</Grid>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just add the another grid and add it to a certain grid cell on the parent container. (If nested is the way you want to go)

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting grids I suggest using only one grid and defining `Grid.ColumnSpan="4"` on the content of row0col1, row3col1 and row4col1.